# how to make tooltip for TextField material ui react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have `TextField` I want the tooltip show when the `length` of that `TextField` less then 5

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

export default function ArrowTooltips() {
  const [currentApp, setCurrentApp] = useState({})
  const handleChange = (event, name) => {
    setCurrentApp({ ...currentApp, [name]: event.target.value })
  }
  return (
    <Tooltip title="Add" arrow open={currentApp.Name.lenght < 5 ? true : false}>
      <TextField value = {currentApp.Name} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, "name")}/>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```

how to make something like this

```
<Tooltip title="Add" arrow open={currentApp.Name.lenght < 5 ? true : false}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:-

1. There is typo in `length`
2. At first render, `currentApp` will be blank object so when we access `name` from blank object it will return undefined so when trying to find length of undefined it will throw error. To solve this we should use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)
3. on input change you should call `handleChange` function.

Try something like below:-

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

export default function ArrowTooltips() {
  const [currentApp, setCurrentApp] = useState({})

  const handleChange = (event, name) => {
    setCurrentApp({ ...currentApp, [name]: event.target.value })
  }
  return (
    <Tooltip title="Add" arrow open={currentApp?.name?.length < 5 ? true : false}>
      <TextField value={currentApp.name} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "name")}/>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```